# Comparison between different PoE HATs

Tags: poe

There are now multiple PoE HATs available:

- [Official Raspberry Pi PoE HAT](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/poe-hat/)
- [LoveRPi PoE HAT](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WD7HXSQ)
- [PiSupply Pi PoE Switch HAT](https://uk.pi-supply.com/products/pi-poe-switch-hat-power-over-ethernet-for-raspberry-pi)

I need to choose which one to use for my project.

I already know from reading the product pages in detail that:

- The Official HAT does not allow to connect other HATS without soldering because it does not pass through the pin header. The fan is said to be quite noisy.
- The PiSupply HAT [cannot do Gigabit Ethernet](https://github.com/PiSupply/PiPoE/tree/0c9c9ae22806f67fb0cc19e4bd6a73f4120a0569#gigabit-ethernet). (No idea if the other ones can.)
- Using external PoE splitters (like [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B074Y6M67F/)) often produces the same Gigabit Ethernet problem.
- The LoveRPi HAT is not isolated, and connecting the Pi to another grounded device like a monitor over HDMI will kill the Pi (see product description and Amazon comments).
- Some other

Beyond this, can anybody provide or link to a proper, full comparison with pros and cons of the options new available for PoE HATs, or at least of the general approaches on which the different devices are based?

Comment: This is a real depressing list of options. I usually like to use the passive cooling options, but with any of those HATs that's not an option anymore either.

Comment: It looks like LoveRPi's now has an isolated option: https://www.loverpi.com/products/loverpi-poe-hat-for-raspberry-pi-4

Answer (score 2):

Use the official one. While soldering may be a pain, it is possible. You can also replace the fan with another one.